# Paging results from Core Data requests

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I have a relatively simple core data sqlite database. I am trying to get results from DB one page at a time.

```
    NSFetchRequest* request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setEntity:[...]];

    [request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"flaggedTime != nil"]];

    NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"flaggedTime" ascending:NO];
    [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];

    [request setFetchLimit:pageSize];
    [request setFetchOffset:((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize)];    

    NSArray* results = [self.context executeFetchRequest:request error:NULL];
```

pageSize is 30, pageIndex on testing data is 1, 2, 3 or 4 (there are about 80 items in DB, so pageIndex = 4 should return no items).
Predicate and sorting works fine, results are successfully returned. Fetch limit works fine, too. No errors are returned.

Problem: I always get results from the first page, as if fetchOffset was not set. I tried to remove the predicate and the sorting but to no avail.
The only situation when I could make fetchOffset work was when I used values under 30. Of course, that is meaningless for paging...

Does anybody know why? I will be really thankful for every answer.

Update: I am speaking about iOS. Tested on 4.2 and 5.0.

Update 2: To simplify the problem.

```
    NSFetchRequest* request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setEntity:[...];

    NSError* error = nil;

    NSManagedObjectContext* context = [...];

    NSUInteger count = [context countForFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    assert(error == nil);

    NSLog(@"Total count: %u", count);

    request.fetchOffset = 0;    
    request.fetchLimit = 30;

    NSLog(@"Fetch offset: %u, limit: %u", request.fetchOffset, request.fetchLimit);

    NSArray* page1 = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    assert(error == nil);

    NSLog(@"Page 1 count: %u", page1.count);

    request.fetchOffset = 30;    
    request.fetchLimit = 30;

    NSLog(@"Fetch offset: %u, limit: %u", request.fetchOffset, request.fetchLimit);

    NSArray* page2 = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    assert(error == nil);

    NSLog(@"Page 2 count: %u", page2.count);
```

gives:

```
Total count: 34
Fetch offset: 0, limit: 30
Page 1 count: 30
Fetch offset: 30, limit: 30
Page 2 count: 30 (ERROR: should give 4)
```

Comment: Could we see the code where you set pageSize and pageIndex? Also, the code where you display the results?

Comment: That is not relevant. The problem is here. I understand that you don't believe me and you expect to find a simple solution somewhere else but the parameters that come into the method are what I have written above. But I am curious - do you actually have a working code which uses both fetchLimit and fetchOffset?

Comment: I have working code that uses fetchLimit, fetchOffset and sortDescriptors - just like you do. and my code works fine.

Comment: Can there be a difference when opening the DB or request set up? I know that the docs state "Offsets are ignored in nested requests such as subqueries." but I think my request is really simple.

Comment: Where you compute "((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize)", I would introduce a separate variable, and log it before you set it as the fetch offset. Based on everything else you're saying, the values coming into building your offset may not be what you're expecting. When it seems like all the right APIs are being called, it's often some simple assumption/oversight.

Comment: I know. What I am actually logging is request.fetchOffset after I set it.

Comment: Updated the question to show the actual values.

Comment: How important is it to actually page these results? [NSFetchedResultsController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) provides dynamic row loading and caching. Quite specific to UITableView, but useful none the less.

Comment: @jsapara Using a different class does not explain why this code does not work. I don't want workarounds.

Comment: in your exemple, does page2 containing the last 30 elements or the first 30 elements?

Comment: Always the first 30 elements.

Comment: @Sulthan You may have to share your momd file to help reproduce the error.

Comment: Good idea. I'll try to simplify it a little (it contains confidental information) and share it with you.

Comment: Did you manage to find the solution to this problem?

Comment: @user1078065 Unfortunately, I didn't. As mentioned in the highest-voted answer, the problem is local, probably caused by the model somehow but I never got to inspect the model in detail.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It would be interesting to find out what's going on.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `pageOffset` property of `NSFetchRequest` is (sometimes?) ignored when you run fetch requests against an unsaved context. Note how in the code by OP context is never saved, while in the code snippet attached to an answer by @kcharwood it is actually saved. Here is an example:

```
- (void) printArrayOfTestEntities:(NSArray *)array{
    NSMutableString * s = [NSMutableString new];
    NSArray * numbers = [array valueForKey:@"someField"];
    for (NSNumber * number in numbers){
        [s appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d ", [number intValue]]];
    }

    NSLog(@"fetched objects: %@ \rcount: %d", s, array.count);
}

/* example itself */

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
[context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:persistentStoreCoordinator];

for(int i = 0; i < 34;i++){
    NSManagedObject * object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"TestEntity"
                                                      inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [object setValue:@(i) forKey:@"someField"];
}

NSFetchRequest * request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"TestEntity"];
request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"someField" ascending:YES]];
request.fetchLimit = 30;

NSArray * result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
[self printArrayOfTestEntities:result];

request.fetchOffset = 30;
result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
[self printArrayOfTestEntities:result];

[context save:&error];

request.fetchOffset = 0;
result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
[self printArrayOfTestEntities:result];

request.fetchOffset = 30;
result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
[self printArrayOfTestEntities:result];
```

The log:

```
2014-03-01 11:30:06.986 coredatatest[19771:70b] fetched objects: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29  
count: 30
2014-03-01 11:30:06.990 coredatatest[19771:70b] fetched objects: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29  
count: 30
2014-03-01 11:30:06.995 coredatatest[19771:70b] fetched objects: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29  
count: 30
2014-03-01 11:30:06.997 coredatatest[19771:70b] fetched objects: 30 31 32 33   
count: 4
```

Comment: The question iss long overdue and I believe this was the actual problem then. Unsaved context.

Comment: Thanks to this answer, I could find an error in my program. I just want to add that the fetched objects are unsaved ones. I can't believe Apple is not documenting this issue.

Comment: One thing to note - this example works because the context you are using is the base context and not a child of it. Running the same sort of scenario in a child context will still give bad results even if saved until the changes are saved to the persistent store. This is because the fetchOffset property relies on sqlite and a db on disk to function. This should really cause a warning in objective-c, but instead they just give back bad results.

Answer (score 21):

I just created a demo project that tries to recreate your scenario at its simplest form.  I created a blank project, added 34 objects, then queried it with the exact same code you listed above.  Below is the example:

```
CDAppDelegate * delegate = (CDAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext * context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
for(int i = 0; i < 34;i++){
    CDObject * object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CDObject"
                                                      inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [object setValue:i];
}
[delegate saveContext];

NSFetchRequest* request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CDObject"
                               inManagedObjectContext:context]];

 NSError* error = nil;

 NSUInteger count = [context countForFetchRequest:request error:&error];
 assert(error == nil);

 NSLog(@"Total count: %u", count);

 request.fetchOffset = 0;    
 request.fetchLimit = 30;

 NSLog(@"Fetch offset: %u, limit: %u", request.fetchOffset, request.fetchLimit);

 NSArray* page1 = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
 assert(error == nil);

 NSLog(@"Page 1 count: %u", page1.count);

 request.fetchOffset = 30;    
 request.fetchLimit = 30;

 NSLog(@"Fetch offset: %u, limit: %u", request.fetchOffset, request.fetchLimit);

 NSArray* page2 = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
 assert(error == nil);

 NSLog(@"Page 2 count: %u", page2.count);

[request release];
```

The log is as shown:

```
2011-11-04 14:53:04.530 CDCoreDataTest[77964:207] Total count: 34
2011-11-04 14:53:04.531 CDCoreDataTest[77964:207] Fetch offset: 0, limit: 30
2011-11-04 14:53:04.532 CDCoreDataTest[77964:207] Page 1 count: 30
2011-11-04 14:53:04.533 CDCoreDataTest[77964:207] Fetch offset: 30, limit: 30
2011-11-04 14:53:04.533 CDCoreDataTest[77964:207] Page 2 count: 4
```

Using your code, I was able to get it up and running no problem.  This was done with iOS 5.0 running on the simulator.  Your code looks right to me for you are trying to accomplish, so there must be something going on with the fetch request or the context itself...

Comment: I think the OP's problem is a conceptual confusion with "page" and "paging". There is nothing inherently page-like in this implied data model or the explicit code. He's not "paging" through anything as the term is usually used in programming.

Comment: Still trying to reproduce the problem on a newly created model. Please, be patient.

Answer (score 0):

Core Data has built in paging and it's super simple, just set fetchBatchSize on the fetch request. When set the fetch just queries for all the objects as faults, basically just a pointer and its row index which is minimal memory into a special kind of array called a batch faulting array. I'd imagine this is fine in most cases although I haven't looked into exactly how much memory it would use for a huge number of rows. Then when you loop this array when you access a faulted record's property it queries the database for that record and the next records up to the number you set for the batch size. This allows you to loop your results one by one as normal, but in the background it loads in the data in batches. As of iOS 9.2 the minimum batch size is 4 so no point setting a number lower than that.