# NSFetchRequest.fetchOffset broke after setting NSManagedObject's property

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I wrote a method to randomly fetch record from database, but I often got the same record no matter what NSFetchRequest.fetchOffset is.

So I did an experiment, here is my code:

```
- (Card *)getNextCard {
    Card *card = nil;
    while (YES) {
        NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Card"];
        request.fetchLimit = 1;
        request.fetchOffset = arc4random_uniform(1031);

        NSError *error = nil;
        NSArray *matches = [self.database.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

        if (matches) {
            card = [matches lastObject];
            // card.phEn= @"phonetic";
        }
        NSLog(@"nextCard: %@, %d", card ? card.en : card, request.fetchOffset);
    }
    return card;
}
```

With above code, log is like:

```
2013-05-07 23:11:16.035 MyApp[20598:707] nextCard: astound, 153
2013-05-07 23:11:17.175 MyApp[20598:707] nextCard: complicate, 370
2013-05-07 23:11:18.335 MyApp[20598:707] nextCard: hasten, 954
2013-05-07 23:11:19.801 MyApp[20598:707] nextCard: exonerate, 749
2013-05-07 23:11:23.159 MyApp[20598:707] nextCard: exalted, 736
2013-05-07 23:11:24.389 MyApp[20598:707] nextCard: Leninism, 3
2013-05-07 23:11:25.749 MyApp[20598:707] nextCard: commotion, 360
2013-05-07 23:11:27.959 MyApp[20598:707] nextCard: discern, 565
2013-05-07 23:11:28.895 MyApp[20598:707] nextCard: aluminum, 85
```

which was perfectly fine.

But when I uncommented this line:

> // card.phEn= @"phonetic";

log became:

```
2013-05-07 23:25:02.183 MyApp[20645:707] nextCard: annex, 104
2013-05-07 23:25:04.042 MyApp[20645:707] nextCard: annex, 614
2013-05-07 23:25:06.095 MyApp[20645:707] nextCard: annex, 926
2013-05-07 23:25:07.393 MyApp[20645:707] nextCard: annex, 628
2013-05-07 23:25:08.968 MyApp[20645:707] nextCard: annex, 809
2013-05-07 23:25:10.316 MyApp[20645:707] nextCard: annex, 265
2013-05-07 23:25:11.534 MyApp[20645:707] nextCard: annex, 762
```

It seems no matter what fetchOffset is, it always return the same object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Paging results from Core Data requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955486/paging-results-from-core-data-requests)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be caused by the fact that your context has unsaved (pending) changed. Unfortunately, this is not really well documented.

You can try to set `includesPendingChanges` to `NO` for your request.

Answer (score 0):

Is your store already populated with Card objects when you call the `getNextCard` method? If so, are you sure that it return the same object? Maybe you should try to NSLog the objectID of the Card object.